# Relative path as parameter of php batch script

Tags: php, batch-file, path, absolute

I've been googlin around, trying to find the specific solution to my issue if any... I have a batch script running a php command which then run a phpscript to load data to mysql database

here's the command

```
set PHP = c:\xampp\php\php.exe
%PHP% -f c:/xampp/htdocs/xx/cron/export.php
```

Is there a way I could do

```
%PHP% -f xx/cron/export.php
```

same for the %PHP% is there a way I could omit the absolute path, this design/approach is a poor program design, and I want to make sure I would be implementing what is right.

Please help me on how to implement this correctly.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can try with :

```
set PHP = cd c:\xampp\htdocs\ & c:\xampp\php\php.exe
```

This will execute php.exe in the c:/xampp/htdocs environment, so the `xx/cron/export.php` file will be found.